# Recovery Mode Can't Install OS X Mavericks (Late 2009 iMac)

Tags: macos, imac, startup, recovery

I have a wiped iMac (27-Inch "Core i5" 2.66 - Late 2009) that boots into recovery mode. When I try to install OS X (Mavericks) It says "An error occurred while preparing the installation. Try running this app again." Restarting it does not help.

EDIT:
Computer was on Yosemite before wiped (I'm 90% sure). `Diskutil list` does not return anything useful and `diskutil cs list` says No CoreStorage logical volume groups found.

sw_vers returns:

ProductName:    Mac OS X

ProductVersion: 10.9.2

BuildVersion: 13C64

Comment: What OS was on it last? When you wiped it did you also wipe the Recovery Partition; are you currently booted to Recovery or to Internet Recovery? Can you get to Terminal & provide the results of `diskutil list` &/or `diskutil cslist` [only one will give a sensible result]

Comment: I believe there are no 2009 Mac models can use [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313). Can you also post the output from the command `sw_vers`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - D'oh, yes. 2011 earliest. My bad.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: That command should be `diskutil cs list` (spaces matter).

Comment: Why not download a more recent OS X (like 10.13.6) and make a bootable installer? Links are all here https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-download-macos-catalina-mojave-or-high-sierra-full-installers/

Comment: Do you have an optical disk or any hard disk drives, solid state drives, flash drives or thumb drives plugged directly or indirectly into the Mac? Did you enter `diskutil list` or `Diskutil list`? If you did enter `diskutil list`, there is little chance nothing useful was returned. Here is the problem I have with your question: If you actually wiped your Mac, then how are you booting to recovery mode? If the internal drive(s) are truly wiped, then there would be no recovery partition to boot from. If there is a recovery partition, then `diskutil list` would show this partition.